# weblogic 12c with richfaces 4.0.0 - For <rich:fileUpload> Deployment Failed

Tags: file-upload, richfaces, weblogic12c

Issue when I try to deploy in to weblogic 12C

Steps that I followed,

- JSTL - 1.2
- JSF - 1.2
- richfaces-rich-4.5.17.Final
- richfaces-a4j-4.5.17.Final
- richfaces-core-4.5.17.Final

Also I included,

- guava-18.0.jar
- cssparser-0.9.19.jar
- sac-1.3.jar
- annotations-4.0.0.Final.jar

Deployment was successful, but when I tried to upload a file using `<rich:fileUpload>` I got the following error:

> The JSF implementation 1.0.0.0_2-1-5 does not support the RichFaces ExtendedPartialViewContext. Please upgrade to at least Mojarra 2.1.28 or 2.2.6

Then I upgrade JSF1.2 to jsf-api-2.1.28 and jsf-impl-2.1.28 with Richfaces 4.5.17.

When I try to file upload received:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: IO Error parsing multipart request
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:242)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:216)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:132)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:352)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:75)
        at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:343)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:75)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:302)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:367)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:75)
       weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:75)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:75)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3288)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3254)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2163)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2091)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2074)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1512)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: org.ajax4jsf.exception.FileUploadException: IO Error parsing multipart request
        at org.ajax4jsf.request.MultipartRequest.parseRequest(MultipartRequest.java:388)
        at org.richfaces.component.FileUploadPhaselistener.beforePhase(FileUploadPhaselistener.java:63)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleBeforePhase(Phase.java:228)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:99)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
        ... 29 more
```

Found The JSF default version of  12.1.1 WLS server is lower than 2.1.28 JSF version, so I changed JSF version to jsf-api-2.0.0 and jsf-impl-2.0.0 and 
changed RichFaces version from 4.5.17 to:

- richfaces-core-api-4.0.0.Final
- richfaces-core-impl-4.0.0.Final
- richfaces-components-ui-4.0.0.Final
- richfaces-components-api-4.0.0.Final.

Deployment Failed:

```
<Critical error during deployment:
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: The tag named remove from namespace http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets has a null handler-class defined
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processHandlerClass(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:415)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTags(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:371)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTagLibrary(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:314)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:263)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:362)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Jul 12, 2016 6:29:19 PM SGT> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: The tag named remove from namespace http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets has a null handler-class defined.
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: The tag named remove from namespace http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets has a null handler-class defined
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:582)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: The tag named remove from namespace http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets has a null handler-class defined
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processHandlerClass(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:415)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTags(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:371)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTagLibrary(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:314)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:263)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:362)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I changed web.xml header to:

```
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
```

Please advice for `rich:fileUpload` in WebLogic 12c using RichFaces.

Answer (score 0):

richfaces-xxx-4.5 works with JSF 2. It means you cannot deploy it with JSF 1.2

Comment: Thank you Vasil. I tried but no luck. Now I m using Richfaces 3.3.3 but im facing org.ajax4jsf.exception.FileUploadException: IO Error parsing multipart request
        at org.ajax4jsf.request.MultipartRequest.parseRequest(MultipartRequest.java:388)
        at org.richfaces.component.FileUploadPhaselistener.beforePhase(FileUploadPhaselistener.java:63)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleBeforePhase(Phase.java:228)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:99)
Caused By: java.io.IOException: Request data cannot be read
        
Any Idea ?